# How to create CDATA tag in Excel vba?

Tags: xml, excel, vba, xmldocument, cdata

Can anyone please help.

I am trying to convert excel data into xml file uisng vba.
  My xml file looks  like this,

```
 <product>
  <info><i>Samsung</i></info>
 </product>
```

I want the html tags not to be parsed.so trying to add cdata in vba using createCDATASection method in vba

I added vba code  like this

```
  Set objDom = New DOMDocument
  Set objXMLRootelement = objDom.createElement("Product")
  Set objXMLelement = objDom.createElement("info")
  objXMLRootelement.appendChild objXMLelement
  cdata=objDom.createCDATASection ("<i>Samsung</i>")
  objXMLelement.text=cdata.text
```

I want my xml file to appear like this and when viewed the viewsource in notepad it should
display '<' as '<' but not 'ampersand lt;'

```
  <product>
    <info><![CDATA[<i>Samsung</i>]]></info>
  </product>
```

after executing my code it is displaying like this,

```
  <product>
   <info><i>Samsung</i></info>
  </product>
```

but cdata tag is not appearing.Dont know the reason.And when viewed the view source of the xml file  in notepad '<' symbol is shown as ampersand lt;

can anyone please solve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
Sub zx()
    Dim objDom As DOMDocument
    Dim objXMLRootelement As IXMLDOMElement
    Dim objXMLelement As IXMLDOMElement
    Dim cdata As IXMLDOMCDATASection

    Set objDom = New DOMDocument
    Set objXMLRootelement = objDom.createElement("Product")
    objDom.appendChild objXMLRootelement
    Set objXMLelement = objDom.createElement("info")
    objXMLRootelement.appendChild objXMLelement
    Set cdata = objDom.createCDATASection("info")
    cdata.Data = "<i>Samsung</i>"
    objXMLelement.appendChild cdata

    Debug.Print objDom.XML
End Sub
```

Comment: Awesome!! Got it! I have been trying from two days.Got solved! Thankyou very much for your answer

Comment: Thanks, happy to help.  BTW, SO protocol is to accept answers that solve your problem (click the tick)

Answer (score 0):

The example is a little bit redundant. It sets the the data twice. First in the initialiser:

```
Set cdata = objDom.createCDATASection("info")
```

This is actually creating the cdata object **AND** simultaneously writing "info" as the data. More faithfull to the original poster's question would be:

```
Set cdata = objDom.createCDATASection("<i>Samsung</i>")
```

Additionally the object's data property can also be used as already if this is more convenient:

```
cdata.Data = "<i>Samsung</i>"
```

Neither is correct but it's not necessary to do set the data property twice.